# Adding picture using ContentProviderOperation gives "Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException" error

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to fill the contact picture using an Image but it's showing error while filling it. Below is my code:

```
Bitmap mBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/home/sandeepyadav/AndroidStudioProjects/Apps/mitapp/app/src/main/res/raw/image1.jpg");
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int rawContactID = ops.size();
if(mBitmap!=null) {
    mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 75, stream);
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, stream.toByteArray())
        .build());
}
```

I am getting this error:

> 08-23 12:34:30.151 9308-9308/com.mmx.mitapp E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/sandeepyadav/AndroidStudioProjects/Apps/mitapp/app/src/main/res/raw/image1.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: here is a hint `No such file or directory`

Comment: I already provide the correct path for the file